# Why is my Vuejs method call producing an infinite loop when I'm not even using a loop?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, vuejs2, axios, sharepoint-online

My browser is IE 11.

I have a SharePoint-online page using vue and Vuetify.  I am using the [simple table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/simple-tables) component from vuetify to display my data.  I added my simple table to a vue component that extends my Vue instance.  I'm also using REST API to filter a SharePoint list to return a single value when a method is called. For some odd reason, that I can't figure out, when I make my API call to retrieve the single value I get an infinite loop and I'm not using a v-for.  The values get returned but I see the rendered values switching through numbers on the page and eventually leads to a SharePoint throttling problem.  Here's the code:

```
Vue.component('my-msr-input',{
    data: function() {
        return {
            retentionList: [],
            lcat: [],
            num:0
        }
    },
    template: "      \n  <v-simple-table dense>    \n            <thead>      \n                <tr>\n                    <th class=\"text-left\" width=\"10px\">Position</th>\n                    <th class=\"text-left\" width=\"10px\">ART</th>\n                    <th class=\"text-left\" width=\"10px\">PRO</th>\n                    <th class=\"text-left\" width=\"10px\">TAP</th>                  \n                </tr>\n            </thead>\n            <tbody>\n                <tr>\n                    <td>Junior Operations Research Analyst</td>\n                    <td>{{ getMsrInputData('ART','Research Analyst') }}</td>\n                    <td></td>\n                    <td></td>                    \n                </tr>  \n                <tr>\n                    <td>Journeyman Operations Research Analyst</td>\n                    <td>{{ getMsrInputData('ART','Operations Analyst') }}</td>\n                    <td></td>\n                    <td></td>                    \n                </tr>   \n            </tbody>\n        </v-simple-table>";
   methods: {
        getMsrInputData: function(title,pos){                      
            endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('TrackPositions')/items?$select=Lists&$filter=substringof('"+ title +"',%20Title)%20and%20(POSITION%20eq '"+ pos +"')";

            var vm = this;
                axios.get(endPointUrl).then(function(response){
                    vm.num = response.data.value.length;
                    console.log(response.data.value.length)
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error)
                }).then(function(){                    

                })

                return this.num;                
        },

    },
    computed: {

    }
})
```

I expect a table in the form of a matrix with single values in each cell.  Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your vue instance look like?

Comment: I'm actually using a vue component to extend the instance.  I'll modify my question to reflect that.